# What is the easiest way to read the text file delimited by tab in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the best and easiest way to read the text file delimited by tab in python? I want to convert first column of text file into a list escaping first line (header).

```
import csv
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_row = [column[0] for column in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')]
    print (first_row)
```

The code above gives all the elements of first_column. How can I escape first line (header)?

Comment: Changing the question to something different will make the answer you've already accepted confusing for other readers.  In the future I'd suggest creating a new question instead.

Comment: ok, i have asked new question for that, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in the question, but why not just slice off the first element of the list?

```
import csv
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_column = [row[0] for row in csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')]
    print (first_column[1:])
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you load the file, you can access data by column name. In this example, `FirstColName` is the first column name of the loaded file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\hydro\a.txt", sep='\t')
firstCol = np.asarray(file.FirstColName)
print (firstCol)
```